# Whenever I run my code the screen goes blank with no error message

Tags: python, pygame

```
    import pygame       #setup

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))                    
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_caption("Smley Pong")
keepGoing = True
pic = pygame.image.load("Crazysmile.bmp")
colorkey = pic.get_at((0,0))
pic.set_colorkey(colorkey)
picx = 0
picy = 0
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
speedx = 5
speedy = 5
paddlew = 200
paddleh = 25
paddley = 550
picw = 100
pich = 100
points = 0
lives = 5
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times", 24)

while keepGoing:      # Game loop

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keepGoing = False
picx += speedx
picy += speedy

if picx <= 0 or picx + pic.get_width() >= 800:
    speedx = -speedx
if picy <= 0:
    speedy = -speedy
if picy >= 500:
    lives -= 1
    speedy = -speedy

screen.fill(BLACK)
screen.blit(pic, (picx, picy))

# Draw Paddle
paddlex = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
paddlex = paddlew/2
pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (paddlex, paddley, paddlew, paddleh))

# Check for paddle bounce
if picy + pich >=paddley and picy + pich <=paddley + paddleh \
   and speedy > 0:
    if picx +picw / 2 >= paddlex and picx +picw / 2 <= paddlex + \
       paddlew:
        points += 1
        speedy = -speedy

# Draw text on screen
draw_screen = "Lives: " + str(lives) + "points: " + str(points)
# Check whether game is over
if lives < 1:
    speedx = speedy = 0
     draw_String = "Game Over.Your score was: " + str(points)                                                 draw_string += ". Press F1 to play again. "

text = font.render(draw_string, True, WHITE)
text_rect = text.get_rect()
text_rect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
text.rect.y = 10
screen.bilt(text, text_rect)
pygame.display.update()
timer.tick(60)

pygame.quit()    # Exit
```

This is a pong game with using the help of a book, i wanted to test out
pygame but the screen just went blank, so i searched up if anyone had the same problem but they all had different answers so i couldn't fix it.I added a few extra parts but if you think i dont need them or you want me to add something just say what you think i should do.
 If there are any suggestions please answer, also recommendations also answer.

Comment: Fix your indentation please

Comment: Are you sure you don't get an error message?  I can see several errors:

    1) 'bilt' instead of 'blit'
    2) you have timer.tick(60) but you named your clock object 'Clock' - there's no 'timer' variable anywhere

Other than that, it's really hard to read the code with the indenting messed up.  Fix that, and we can try running your code to see what else is wrong.

Comment: There is a lot going on here that you need to understand before trying to implement it in code. Start with the basics such as displaying a white screen or moving a square across the screen. Then you can grasp basic game programming.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to indent your code from the line `picx += speedx`, to the line before `pygame.quit()`

You will then have to add in `pygame.display.flip()` before the line `pygame.quit()`(and indent it!)

Then the line `text.rect.y = 10` does not make sense. `font.render()` returns a surface and you can only set the `x` and `y` positions when you `blit()`.

also the line:

```
draw_String = "Game Over.Your score was: " + str(points)                                                 draw_string += ". Press F1 to play again. "
```

has some wierd indentation.

you will also have to add `timer = pygame.time.Clock()` somewhere after the import of pygame.